# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for

Tags: python, django

this error is killing me please help I sat on in like for 3 hours and I couldn't even know why is the error happening I will give all the information needed , btw I am new to Django so please explain if you can Thank You,
Error:

NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'change_friends' with keyword arguments '{'operation': 'add', 'pk': 2}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['connect/(P.+)/(P\d+)/']

Here is my views.py

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from home.forms import HomeForm
from home.models import Post, Friend


class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home/home.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created')
        users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
        try:
            friend = Friend.objects.get(current_user=request.user)
            friends = Friend.users.all()
        except Friend.DoesNotExist:
            friends = None

        args = {
            'form': form, 'posts': posts, 'users': users, 'friends': friends
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self, request):
        form = HomeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()

            text = form.cleaned_data['post']
            form = HomeForm()
            return redirect('home:home')

        args = {'form': form, 'text': text}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

def change_friends(request, operation, pk):
    friend = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if operation == 'add':
        Friend.make_friend(request.user, friend)
    elif operation == 'remove':
        Friend.lose_friend(request.user, friend)
    return redirect('home:home')
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Friend(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    current_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @classmethod
    def make_friend(cls, current_user, new_friend):
        friend, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            current_user=current_user
        )
        friend.users.add(new_friend)

    @classmethod
    def lose_friend(cls, current_user, new_friend):
        friend, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            current_user=current_user
        )
        friend.users.remove(new_friend)
```

Urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from home.views import HomeView
from . import views
app_name= 'home'
urlpatterns = [
    url('', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    url('connect/(P<operation>.+)/(P<pk>\d+)/', views.change_friends, name='change_friends')
]
```

Html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h2>Home</h2>
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.post }}
            <br>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <h2>{{ text }}</h2>
        {% for post in posts %}
            <h1>{{ post.post }}</h1>
            <p>Posted by {{ post.user.get_full_name }} on {{ post.created }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Other People</h2>
        {% for user in users %}
            <a href="{% url 'accounts:view_profile_with_pk' pk=user.pk %}">
                <h3>{{ user.username }}</h3>
            </a>
            {% if not user in friends %}
            <a href="{% url 'home:change_friends' operation='add' pk=user.pk %}">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add Friend</button>
            </a>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <h2>Friends</h2>
        {% for friend in friends %}
            <a href="{% url 'accounts:view_profile_with_pk' pk=friend.pk %}">
                <h3>{{ friend.username }}</h3>
            </a>
            <a href="{% url 'home:change_friends' operation='remove' pk=friend.pk %}">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Remove Friend</button>
            </a>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

TraceBack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\Desktop\Alone-Osama\home\views.py", line 25, in get
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 312, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\daghe\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /
Exception Value: Reverse for 'change_friends' with keyword arguments '{'operation': 'add', 'pk': 2}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['connect/(P<operation>.+)/(P<pk>\\d+)/']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried with this url path and is working

```
path('connect/<str:operation>/<int:pk>/', 
views.change_friends, name='change_friends'),
```